# Downloading file from web in java

Tags: java

I am using the following Java code to download data from web. There are instances where it works fine. However, sometimes it gives errors. What can be the reason?

There is no difference in URL as I have copied it from their site as well : 
http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/07-04-2010-TO-01-04-2011TCSALLN.csv

My URL is:
http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/07-04-2010-TO-01-04-2011TCSALLN.csv

So, I see no difference.

ERROR:   NOT FOUND: The requested object does not exist on this server. The link you followed is either outdated, inaccurate, or the server has been instructed not to let you have it.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class AutomatedDownloader
{
    private static FileOutputStream fos;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        String combo = "TCS";
        String userDate = "02-04-2011";

        Date date1, date2, date3;

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();      

        date1 = formatter.parse(userDate);

        cal.setTime(date1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        date2 = cal.getTime();
        String endDate = df.format(date2);
        System.out.println(endDate);

        cal.setTime(date1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, - 360);
        date3 = cal.getTime();
        String startDate = df.format(date3);
        System.out.println(startDate);

        String url ="http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/"+startDate+"-TO-"+endDate+combo+"ALLN.csv";
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Parin\\Documents\\ParinAndroid\\StockPredictor\\DownloadedData\\"+combo+".csv";

        URL website = new URL(url);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.print("done");
    }
```

**Exception**:

```
Exception: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/07-12-2013-TO-01-12-2014TCSALLN.csv
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1243)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1009)
        at Predictor.AutomatedDownloader.main(AutomatedDownloader.java:46)
```

Comment: I am also facing same problem...I think NSE India doesn't support that.. I passes that link to browser and it downloads using Desktop class

Comment: I am able to fetch the files sometimes. So, NSE does support it.

Comment: I tried you code. I am getting a FileNotFoundException. Can you please add the exception to your question? You might want to check the response code that is returned. It might be 404

Comment: How do I check the response code? What is that?

Comment: The server is giving response code 404.

Comment: The 404 or Not Found error message is an HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

However, if you go to http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm and select those to end dates, you will get the same URL and you will be able to fetch data.

Comment: What options did you select on the link you have given?

Comment: @Raj can you explain again how you got that URL in detail? I mean, I opened your link and tried to choose the start date and end data then pressed the get data button and I looked at their javascript function, it don't return a file. It will return an html which a function will embed it inside tag with id `historicalData` though.

Comment: I have posted the code that worked for me! Please try! You will have to download the Jsoup jar and add it to your class path.

Comment: Visit http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm

Enter Symbol as TCS and Enter time period. You will get an option to download file as .csv format. Copy link address by right clicking on it

Answer (score 1):

I got the file using [Jsoup](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2) library. Download the Jsoup jar file and add it to your class path. Here's the code:

**Imports**:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
```

**Code**:

```
//Open a URL Stream
Response resultImageResponse = Jsoup
                .connect("http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/07-04-2010-TO-01-04-2011TCSALLN.csv")
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .execute();

// output here
FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("" + "file.csv")));
out.write(resultImageResponse.bodyAsBytes());           
out.close();
```

Comment: @NiRRaNjANRauT: I have tested this code and it is working fine for me. The problem lies in not specifying the user agent. Is this code giving you any problem?

Comment: I just checked the url in my browser and its actually a 404 error. So, this code is very much the working one! I have added the imports needed.

Comment: I am getting the following error: 

Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/07-04-2010-TO-01-04-2011TCSALLN.csv
 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)

Comment: Is this happening when the site is up? Because when I tried it whenever site was up and running, my code worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String index = "cnx nifty junior";
    String from_date = "01-03-2015";
    String to_date = "20-03-2015";
    download(index, from_date, to_date);
}

public static void download(String index, String from_date, String to_date) {
    String link = "http://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/indices/historicalindices.jsp?indexType=" + index.replaceAll(" ", "%20").toUpperCase() + "&fromDate=" + from_date + "&toDate=" + to_date;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            html.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html.toString());
        Elements elements = document.getElementsByTag("a");
        Iterator<Element> iterator = elements.iterator();
        String downloadLink = null;
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Element element = iterator.next();
            downloadLink = "http://www.nseindia.com" + element.attr("href");
        }
        if (downloadLink != null) {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                rt.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + downloadLink);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

it download success. You need to add jsoup.jar library. But it'll work only on windows os.

Comment: If this has worked for you, please post an answer without the error.